# strip_tags and html_entity_decode combination doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, html

I've been battling this issue since yesterday - unfortunately to no avail (not entirely, I've found some sort of a workaround), and after some research and rereading documentation I'm still little dumbfounded and confused.

Let's assume there is an ugly string, which has already special chars properly html encoded. like this :

```
$exampleString = '&amp;lt;div id="dynamic2"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div
id="iStoreProductLongDescription" class="iStoreBox"&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;div class="iStoreBoxWrapper"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div 
class="iStoreBoxContent"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style="text-
align:justify;"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style="text-
align:justify;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="font-
size:large;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span&amp;gt; Just a bunch of text here, at 
the end. yedyedyed';
```

Now I'd like output this string as a simple, clean string, so at first I'll need to convert it to html tags, and then strip the tags. So I guess the following chain should work:

```
$result = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($exampleString));
```

but it doesn't, the output of echo $result in the source of the web is:

```
&lt;div id="dynamic2"&gt; &lt;div id="iStoreProductLongDescription" class="iStoreBox"&gt; &lt;div class="iStoreBoxWrapper"&gt; &lt;div class="iStoreBoxContent"&gt; &lt;p style="text-align:justify;"&gt; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p style="text-align:justify;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:large;"&gt;&lt;span&gt; Just a bunch o text here, at the end. yedyedyed
```

In the user output html tags are visible and remain untouched. However when I do something like this:

```
$result = strip_tags(html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($exampleString)));
```

then it works like a charm and outputs desired string both to the user and the same is in the web source:

> Just a bunch o text here, at the end. yedyedyed

The question stands - why doesn't

```
strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($exampleString));
```

work as (I presume) it should work? 
Any insight much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer you will see that you have

`&amp;lt;` and it's not `&lt;`.

So, you first `htmlspecialchars_decode` just converts

`&amp;lt;` to `&lt;`

which is surely a special entity, which can later be decoded with second run of `htmlspecialchars_decode` (or `html_entity_decode`) to `<`, but not removed with `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as like that:

```
$exampleString = '&amp;lt;div id="dynamic2"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div
id="iStoreProductLongDescription" class="iStoreBox"&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;div class="iStoreBoxWrapper"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div 
class="iStoreBoxContent"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style="text-
align:justify;"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p style="text-
align:justify;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="font-
size:large;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span&amp;gt; Just a bunch of text here, at 
the end. yedyedyed';

$result = htmlspecialchars_decode($exampleString); // this will decode the entities
echo $result;
```

**Result Should be:**

```
<div id="dynamic2"> <div
id="iStoreProductLongDescription" class="iStoreBox">
<div class="iStoreBoxWrapper"> <div 
class="iStoreBoxContent"> <p style="text-
align:justify;"> </p> <p style="text-
align:justify;"><span style="font-
size:large;"><span> Just a bunch of text here, at 
the end. yedyedyed
```

**After html_entity_decode():**

```
$result = html_entity_decode($result); // this will print with HTML
echo $result;
```

**Result Should be (with html tags):**

```
 Just a bunch of text here, at 
the end. yedyedyed
```

**After strip_tags():**

```
$result = strip_tags($result); // this will strip your html tags
$echo $result;
```

**Result Should be (without html tags):**

```
 Just a bunch of text here, at 
the end. yedyedyed
```

Comment: @u_mulder: yes i see, so i have shared the explanation.